# Comparison of Option-Pricing Models (volatility models) vs Product-Mapping

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-volatility

I scoured this forum, looking for some indicative (updated as of year 2021) comparison of volatility/option-pricing models. There were some, but they seem dispersed and lacking in general details...
Are there any good papers/forums where there is a good summary? Not looking for anything exhaustive, but along the lines of pros/cons/limitations.
For example, I found this : https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2272823 ... but it's back in 2013 (and won't have been adapted to recent changes)....

I'll start, for example

1. Replication/Terminal Distribution SABR
   The default pricing-model for European Swaptions, both in Interest-Rate and somewhat in FX Vanilla Options. Standard variation now (2022) is on a zero-shift, lognormal OR a bachelier Normal-distribution model.
   Pros : easy implementation; decomposed into Formula-based; well-understood and 'hedged' by traders, efficient computation.
   Cons : only for terminal products (no Bermudanality), Zero-bound failure in pdf (probability distribution -> but solved using zero-shift)
2. Short-rate Models (Hull-White or Vasicek).
   Seldom-used now, except for simplistic Bermudan-style options with close-to-ATM strike options
   Pros : Can be used for Bermudan products; can be decomposed into Formula-based; efficient computation.
   Cons : Only one parameter for volatility-skew (i.e. cannot capture vol-skew), mainly for ATM products then; Hull-White can have negative rates; cannot replicate curve-twist dynamics unless adding more factors
3. Libor Market-Models (LMM)
   Default model mainly used for American-style and/or Bermudan-style products
   Pros : Able to describe complete market-dynamics per the Libor markets -> correlation, caplet vols
   Cons : Need extension to volatility, to capture vol-skew; computationally expensive, can only use Monte-Carlo; Cannot be formula based to easily price (European Swaptions) and efficient computation.

The above are what I have... Did I miss anything?

Kind regards (to all the Option experts/Quants out there!)

Comment: Nice question +1.